# How does the industry embed long lengths of text in html?

Tags: html, text

My main question is how does the industry deal with large amounts of text in HTML tags? I am creating my first website for a blog I want to start and I have all the text inside one paragraph tag and it just looks wrong.  How is it done in the industry?